# PHP / scraping - Get amazon product price

Tags: php, dom, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I am trying to **retrieve** the **price** of an **Amazon product**.
I tried 2 methods:

1. `file_get_contents` -> regex -> **it works**.
2. using **DOMXPath** -> does **not** work for some reason.

I noticed that if **javascript is enabled** the xpath of the price **differs** from the xpath while **javascript is disabled**.

Anyway, how can I retrieve the price using **xpath**?

This is what I am doing but the code returns nothing (even though it is working on any other website):

(The xpath was taken using **firebug**)

```
$url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/product/B00TRQPSXM/';
$path = '/html/body/div[3]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]';

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query($path);

if($elements)
{   
    foreach($elements as $element)
    {
        echo $element->nodeName.'<br>';
        echo $element->nodeValue.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: you're dealing with an external resource. never assume success. ALWAYS check that f_g_c() actually returned useful html. and don't use `@` to suppress errors. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Like MarcB wrote, it's a *bad idea* (tm) to wonder why `dom->loadHTML($html);` does not work when you suppress errors with it. Amazon websites are normally famous for invalid HTML, so you might need some fix/recover operation with it. http://php.net/tidy / http://php.net/class.domdocument#domdocument.props.recover

Answer (score 2):

Your request will be blocked <s>after a couple of tries</s> every time, amazon checks for robot access. Instead of scrapping their site which btw is against amazon's terms of service (or whatever it's called), use their API found at http://developer.amazonservices.com. You will get the price information you are after with [this operation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetCompetitivePricingForASIN.html).

There is also a php sdk you can use.

Either way, `file_get_contents()` is not an option here, if you want to scrape the page use curl and make it look like an unique visitor.

Comment: I am not being blocked. I know I can use the API. The API has some limitation and I am looking for a fallback solution. Never-mind. Why I cannot query the HTML that is being returned by file_get_contents using xpath? On any other website it works fine.

Comment: You don't get the page you are expecting back, you get a error page saying please fill the captcha. As Marc has commented above you just don't see it because you supress errors.

Comment: My question is what the difference between file_get_contents and loadHTML method. This first works, the second not.

Comment: did you ever sorted out how to scrape without getting blocked? I wonder too.